# Time complexity/efficiency of Node.js emitter.removeListener(event, listener)

Tags: javascript, node.js, big-o, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of Node.js' EventEmitter.removeListener(event, listener) method in terms of number of listeners which are bound to a specific event on the emitter?

Link: http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener

Is it O(n) or closer to O(1) for the average case?

Basically, I might have tens of thousands of listeners bound to the same event and I need the removeListener operation to be O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EventEmitter source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L210)

It's O(n) because of the `for` loop on line 230. And after that there's `Array.splice`.

It's O(n) for finding the listener in an array:

```
for (i = length; i-- > 0;) {
  if (list[i] === listener ||
      (list[i].listener && list[i].listener === listener)) {
    position = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

And also O(n) for removing the listener from an array:

```
list.splice(position, 1);
```

Comment: and O(1) if there is only one listener.